# Save File in an Outdated Compiler (Turbo C++)

Tags: c++, save, turbo-c++

Me n my friends are undertaking this personal challenge of coding an entire video game in an outdated IDE (Specifically Turbo C++). Now I'm creating a text based RPG, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to create a save system.

Abt the game: Text based, semi sandbox survival RPG. Player gets kidnapped and needs to get out of a house, while an NPC roams around said house. Think of it kinda as mix between the old school Do It Yourself Goosebumps books, Hello Neighbor and Alien Isolation. I have mapped out the entire interior of the house into blocks, where the player and NPC moves around.

I was thinking of creating a function which whenever the player clicks save, writes a file with the player location, the NPC's location and other info like inventory items, sneak levels etc. But I'm having trouble implementing this system as it also needs to encompass story/objective checkpoints as well. Any suggestions of doing it in a more memory efficient way?

Comment: "_in an outdated IDE_" Technically, not only the IDE is outdated, but it uses non-standard C++, as well, due to it being created, before the first C++ standard.

Comment: Once I implemented a "long-shot-save" in a paint application when a requirement poped-up to save the possible "undo's" as well: I ended up saving all the user's actions and replayed at load. Of course this wasn's a photoshop-like application (since it would be way to heavy), but maybe, it will eas your case a bit.

Comment: Sorry, but thie is really too broad and also very unclear. What specific problems do you have writing the file? Which troubles do you have? You are asking about a _more memory efficient way_, but more efficient than what?

Comment: @Stefan Well that could work

Comment: @Jabberwockywhen I try n write the file n load t, the story checkpoints sometimes wont load, also sometimes the location of the NPC seems getting messed up. As for memory efficiency, idk I was just wondering if theres a more efficient way than just brute recording everything

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Well that IS supposed to be part of the challenge, as during our schooling days we used that IDE. That also the reason I'm running into unwanted bugs n shot and ask stalk overflow :)

Comment: @AmoghShet Just record the state of the game. Where is the problem?

Comment: If you used TurboC++  in school, I hope you went to school long time ago....

Comment: @AmoghShet Fair enough. It's just I wanted to inform you, that it's not only the IDE, that is outdated, in case you didn't know that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Having trouble not with the sandbox features, but the story elements dont keep saving properly. As in NPC says dialogue hes already said, and not supposed to repeat. And no we werent in school that long ago. As far as I know, CBSE schools in India STILL use Turbo C++ (Something I'm mortified about)